# Convert Postgis MultiPoligon Object to GeoJson

Tags: java, json, geometry, postgis, geojson

I work with postgis and I have library for java to select data.now I want to convert this data to Geojson because Geoext need GeoJson Object to display data .Can anybody help me?

```
ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery("select * from a1");
while (resultSet.next()) {
    PGgeometry mp = (PGgeometry) resultSet.getObject("geom");
    MultiPolygon mp1 = (MultiPolygon) mp.getGeometry();
   //TODO
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) in the query, and receive the GeoJSON text from the server.

```
String query = "select ST_GeoJSON(geom) AS geojson, * from a1"
ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery(query);
while (resultSet.next()) {
    String geoJSON = resultSet.getString("geojson");
    /* etc */
}
```